# What is the fingering for this chord arpeggio?

Tags: piano, fingering

Basic question probably, but what would be the best left-hand fingering for this arpeggio?

I was thinking about this: 5 2 1 5 1 5 1 2

[image]

Comment: Very simple to sort out the 1st part, but without the next bar shown, there will be several options. So, as it stands, any answers will be hypothetical, and maybe right, maybe not. Please show more. It isn't the 1st bar in the piece, so what precedes it is also relevant

Comment: I have edit my post to show the chord progression

Comment: So far, so good, but the following bar is also relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fingering you're considering is fine.

I would be likely to use either:

- 5-2-1-4-1-3-1-2 in order to gradually shift my hand along with the shape of the arpeggio, or
- 5-2-1-4(or 3)-1-4(or 3)-1-2, to keep the fingering a bit more consistent.

This all presumes that the note following the passage shown is lower that the final E — enough lower that 2 makes sense on the final E. Were the passage to continue higher, the fingering would change: most likely to 5-2-1-5-1-5-2-5.

The tempo also makes a difference. At high speed, I’d want the fewest possible shifts of hand position without stiffening up.

Answer (score 0):

Your fingering is one good possibilty and Aaron's is another.

I would use 5-2-1-5-2-5-1-2 for the first measure (and end on 5 for the second). This has the advantage of keeping the thumb off the black key.